# How to call an executable from a webapi hosted on server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, process, executable

I am trying to call an executable from a webapi. When I run the code in Visual Studio it works perfect, but when I host it on a test server on IIS it doesn't work. Also I don't get any errors. What am I missing here.? Other functions which doesn't require that executable works fine.

Here is my code.

```
string output = "";
                ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ExeDir");
                var err = "";
                startinfo.FileName = path + @"\Executable.exe";
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = startinfo;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                try
                {
                    process.Start();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    err = e.Message;
                }
```

Comment: How do you verify if it's running in visual studio? Do you have the exe file on the test server? You will not see console output on local machine if you are running exe on test server.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Its running in vs as the expected result by executable is executed. Yes, the file is on the server too. console output is not required as DB action by the exe is happening.

Comment: The running contexts are completely different, so anything can happen, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: @LexLi so.. is there any solution to this.?

Comment: The solution is to know what exactly this executable is doing and does the same in your web app to work under system context. If that task cannot be done under system context, your only option is to give it up and perform the task in a user session.